# How do you build GLFW for VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, glfw

I downloaded it from the glfw website as source.

Used `cmake-gui` with visual studio 2015 as the generator.

I clicked GLFW in the destination folder.
I attempt to start it, but it said:

> Unable to start the program 'E:\glfw-3.1.1\New
>   Folder\Debug\ALL_BUILD'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I can't find any .lib's or anything else I would need.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I opened the GLFW solution, however the default project was not the glfw project. Fixed that and now the lib compiles.